# Three.js raycaster.intersectObject do not intersect when THREE.Points has only 1 vertex or has vertexs arranged in line

Tags: javascript, three.js

I spent several hours to understand this problem. For some inexplicable reason (for me)  `raycaster.intersectObject( pointCloud );` do not intersect my 'pointCloud' Object when it has just one vertex (the respective position array attribute with three elements). If the Object has two or more vertices only then `raycaster.intersectObject` works.

My  geometry is a `THREE.BufferGeometry()` and I'm using a custom `ShaderMaterial`.
My object is a `THREE.Points`.

```
this.pointCloud = new THREE.Points( geometry, material0 );
```

Any ideas?

↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓ New edition of my question ↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓

Ok, I think the problem here is that when I have a `THREE.Point`, with a Buffer Geometry with just one vertex (something really specific and odd, but in my case possible) the calculation for a `boundingBox` `min` and `max`, is :

```
boundingBox: 
  max: 
     THREE.Vector3  x: 50  y: 50  z: -50
  min: 
    THREE.Vector3  x: 50  y: 50  z: -50
```

And the problem is not just with one vertex, with a set of vertexs arranged in the same line (less odd), the min and max of the boundingBox of the geometry draws a line. I mean, for example, same X pos, Y pos, but different Z pos,

```
boundingBox: 
  max: 
    THREE.Vector3 x: -100 y: 0 z: 133
  min: 
    THREE.Vector3 x: -100 y: 0 z: -33
```

So, I think here is why in these both cases raycast intersection do not work.

More details:

In this last case for example, following the thread of the `raycast.intersection`:

```
//in my file.js
intersections = raycaster.intersectObject( pc.pointCloud , true);  
//line 7734 three.js
intersectObject( object, this, intersects, recursive ); 
//line 7678 three.js 
object.raycast( raycaster, intersects ); 
//line 16542 three.js
if ( ray.isIntersectionBox( geometry.boundingBox ) === false ) {... 
//line 6152 three.js
intersectBox: function ( box, optionalTarget ) {...
```

Here, inside this intersectBox function :

```
//line 6188 three.js 
if ( ( tmin > tymax ) || ( tymin > tmax ) ) return null;
```

...the evaluation is true, so returns **null** and the intersections can't be achieved. I assume the problem is that it evaluates the *x* and *y* positions of the boundedBox that are the same, and that's why `( tmin > tymax)` or `(tymin > tmax)` gives `true`. But if I change the position of my particles, to share *x* and *z*, and have *y* as the different one, is the same result, is not intersecting.

Maybe with this new information someone is able to help me to set a good fix for this.

...edit this three.js function?, or do a trick in my geometry to give a valid boundedBox?....

Thanks once again!

Three.js 72

Comment: Just a question on a brief scan of this, are you trying to intersect with infinitely small point, or infinitely thin line perhaps?

Comment: Thanks @beiller. The points I'm using have several sizes, but are not infinitely small, neither the lines. Btw I already have an answer!.

Comment: Points have no volume, it's probably related to your actual answer below. What you think of as a point, is actually a sphere. Cheers!

Comment: Aha!. I think I get it. I had a call to this.geometry.computeBoundingBox() for my geometry, but as you say, points have no volume, using this.geometry.computeBoundingSphere() instead, it solves the problem too, cause is a sphere with a valid radio. Thanks @beiller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@WestLangley gave me the answer in GitHub.

He said:
"Your bounding box has no volume. Try this and report back:

```
 pointCloud.geometry.boundingBox = null;
```

"

I tried and it worked out of the box!. And the detection is working even better than before.

---

Something that @Beiller pointed out in the comments, and is important to include here I think.

I had a call to

```
this.geometry.computeBoundingBox();
```

...for my geometry,  but the points are not volumes, so single point or aligned (in one of the three axis: x, y or z) points are not detected. Using instead:

```
this.geometry.computeBoundingSphere()
```

solve the problem too.