# Raycasting on Point does not work -- THREE.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, raycasting

It looks so basic, however it's not working. Here I create the Point:

```
var p_geo = new THREE.Geometry();
p_geo.vertices = [new THREE.Vec3(0.5, 0,5, 0)];


var p_mat = new THREE.PointsMaterial({size: 0.2 });
var points = new THREE.Points(p_geo, p_mat);
scene.add(points);
```

and here's the raycasting.

```
var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
var mouse = new THREE.Vector2();

function onClick( event ) {

    mouse.x = ( event.clientX / renderer.domElement.clientWidth ) * 2 - 1;
    mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / renderer.domElement.clientHeight ) * 2 + 1;

    raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );


    var intersects = raycaster.intersectObject( points );

    for(var i = 0; i < intersects.length; i++){

        console.log(intersects[i]);
    }

    render();
}

window.addEventListener('click', onClick);
```

Nothings happens when I click the point. What's wrong?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34009220/three-js-raycaster-intersectobject-do-not-intersect-when-three-points-has-only-1 and https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/7710.

Comment: @WestLangley i am doing it. `points.geometry.boundingBox = null;` It does not working

Comment: Raycasting will not work correctly when there is a single point. That is something that needs to be fixed. Maybe try `geometry.computeBoundingSphere(); geometry.boundingSphere.radius +=   0.1;`